# How to manage a lot of connections that must remain open in a single server?

Tags: .net, multithreading, sockets

I'm working in a system that must receive info from a lot of TCP devices (over 3000 devices), this system must have all the connectios open because the devices send alarms and y must show to the GUI the event in Real Time.

I already made the system using one thread to scan each socket that handles the connection with the devices, but I'm experiencing performance issues, because the proccesor cannot handle all this threads.

How can I manage all the opened connections without any lost of events or info and without overload the processor?

I use `TcpListener.AceptSocket` to acept the connections. Then I create a new `Thread` for this method

```
    private void StartTalk()
    {

        DelgateText hand =new  DelgateText(text_texbox1);
        string Line = "";
        while (_Cliente.Connected)
        {  try
            {                  
                bool cb = _Cliente.Poll(100, SelectMode.SelectError);
                _Cliente.ReceiveTimeout = 1000;                
                bool part1 = _Cliente.Poll(1000, SelectMode.SelectRead);
                bool part2 = (_Cliente.Available == 0);
                if (part1 & part2)
                {                        
                    _Cliente.Disconnect(true);
                    offlineClient(this,new Events(false,_Cliente));
                    delagateRemovenik handlerR = new delagateRemovenik(removeCliente);
                    handlerR(_Cliente);
                    delagteList handlist = new delagteList(ActiveClients);
                    ModuloComunicacion ServerActiv = ModuloComunicacion.InstanceModuleComunication;
                    handlist(ServerActiv.GetOnlineClient());                        
                    break;                      
                }
                else {
                    if(_Cliente.Available>0)
                    {
                    byte[] ReaderData = new byte[_Cliente.Available];                       
                    string mensj = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ReaderData, 0, _Cliente.Receive(ReaderData));                            
                    int x0 = _Cliente.ReceiveBufferSize;
                    Line = mensj;
                    hand(_Cliente.RemoteEndPoint.ToString() + "-->" + Line);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                 ex.ToString();
                 break;
            }
         }   
     }
```

All the device will be transmiting info all the time.

Thanks a lot,

Comment: I've done something similar with multiple connection (over 1000 fake devices) with nodejs and socket.io without any loss of performances.

Comment: But the 1000 fake devices was transtiming at the same time?

Comment: What are you using for your connections? Are you polling for input or using non-busy waits for data? Show us some code that accepts connections and reads the data. Typically I use `TcpListener` and `TcpClient` with asynchronous requests, which scales quite well.

Comment: The problem might also be simply that you're trying to process too much data too quickly. Are you talking about 3,000 connections that are continuously transmitting large amounts of data, or 3,000 connections each of which transmits a small amount of data infrequently?

Comment: Thanks @JimMischel, the 3000 will be transmiting info too quickly, because this is for monitoring Alarm Panels and another devices

Comment: [**I/O Completion Ports**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**I/O Completion Ports**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> I/O completion ports provide an efficient threading model for processing multiple asynchronous I/O requests on a multiprocessor system.
>
> Processes that handle many concurrent asynchronous I/O requests can do so more quickly and efficiently by using I/O completion ports in conjunction with a pre-allocated thread pool than by creating threads at the time they receive an I/O request.